# Real height of listview

Tags: android, android-listview

How can I get the real height of a listview contain? I mean that I want to get the height of that control when it has 0 item, 1 item, ... 100 items?

Comment: You want the height in pixels?

Comment: You're going to want to use javascript methods for doing that. After some quick googling, I've seen a few libraries that do that, although I don't know how they behave on the android platform.

Comment: This is the first time I here about javascript on android. So supprise! is it feasible?

Comment: Very! http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449383268/. Let me amend my first comment then... if you're not developing using web languages then you absolutely will NOT want to use Javascript with your app. :)

Comment: Sure! I don't want to use Javascrip any more (although it can). I am developing an android application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The listview is recycling the item views, what you mean by height is the total number of visible items. So if the listview shows X items then no matter how many data you have your listview shows only X. I hope this is what you are asking.

`listView.getChildCount()` - gives you how many items listview can show.

`listView.getCount()`   - gives you the number of items inside the ADAPTER, which is different from the number of visible items (and this is what you are refering to)

Edit: You said need the pixels use `listView.getWidth()` and `listView.getHeight()`

Comment: listView.getHeight() always return the same value any time. That height is the measure height of listview control but I want to get the height of listview-contain.